# Движение объекта к точке. Нажатие на объект

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Интересует как можно реализовать следующее:

Есть объект, он создается в абсолютно рандомном месте на экране. И данному объекту необходимо достичь определенную точку. Каким образом можно это описать? Высчитывать каждый шаг?

А также как можно реализовать проверку тапа на объект. Объекты у меня обычные канвасы с натянутым на них bmp изображением

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать при помощи [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html). Задаете внутри своей вьюхи которая рисует объект. и при каждом тике анимации ([addUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#addUpdateListener(android.animation.ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener))) делаете инвалидейт вьюхи. А как именно реализовать анимацию зависит от того чего вы хотите добиться. Можно менять Rect битмапки, можно транслейтить канвас. Сама троектория задается при помощи [TypeEvaluator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/TypeEvaluator.html).

По поводу тапа на объект вы его рисуете в определенном Rect на канвасе. Так вот у Rect есть метод [contains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html#contains(int,%20int)). В него передаете положение пальца и узнаете внутри rect палец или нет.

Comment: Ну грубо говоря на каждом тике мне надо просто вычислять по 2 точкам объекта который движется и по 2 точкам места назначения вычислять на сколько куда изменить позицию объекта который движется. При этом хорошо было бы поворачивать объект который движется лицом к точке назначения.

Comment: Поворот вы так же можете изменять ObjectAnimator'om. У вас может либо один аниматор этим заниматся либо разные. А так в Evaluator вам приходит фракшен, это относительное время анимации обычно от 0 до 1, он вычисляется при помощи Interpolator'a. И 2 объекта в вашем случае это будут две точки. Точка начала и точка конца. В зависимости от траектории вычисляете по двум точкам и фракшену положение текущей точки и возвращаете его. ObjectAnimator передаст эту точку в объект который вы ему передаете первым параметром. Он вызовет метод setPROPERTY_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

Если не использовать никаких аниматоров, то да считаем каждый шаг. У классов точек Point2D и Point3D есть хороший метод midpoint -средняя точка. Можно создавать траекторию, строя её из средних точек с необходимой детализацией  (вычисление расстояния между точками так же есть у этих классов).